# How to extract a rectangle corner coordinate in Python script

Tags: python, qgis, coordinates

I want to extract a rectangle corner coordinates of a shapefile in Python script... please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 5):

A lot depends on what APIs you have installed.  Since you haven't tagged this post as 'ArcGIS' or 'ESRI', I assume you are not using ArcPy.  Probably the most common Python GIS APIs is OGR.  In OGR do this:

```
import ogr
ds = ogr.Open(r"C:\some_folder\my_subfolder\myShapefile.shp")
lyr = ds.GetLayer(0)
print(lyr.GetExtent())
```

This gives the extent of the entire shapefile.  To get the extent of individual features you must drill down and get their envelopes.

PS: I should have said that the above code give you the extent as (xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax)

**EDIT FOLLOWING COMMENT (26/03/16):**
This will not work on a raster because OGR is a library for vectors.  You need the gdal libraries (these days usually bundled together for any install).  The simplest approach for rasters is to use the [gdalinfo](http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html) utility.

Comment: Hi Sylvester Sneekly, for above code i got the following error..Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/vamsi/.qgis/python/plugins\Transform\dlgTransform.py", line 80, in GetExtent
    print(lyr.GetExtent())
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor........please help..thanks

Comment: That's a very odd error to get here.  Are you diverting the stdout to a file?  BTW I only suggested to print the extent to screen as a quick demo.  You could store it in a file for consumption later in your program instead e.g. "myExtent = lyr.GetExtent()"

Comment: Hi.. Sylvester Sneekly, how can i add the extent values into existing fields like llx,lly
lrx
lry
ulx
uly 
urx
ury

Comment: You need this tutorial: http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/.  It is excellent and will really get you going with GDAL/OGR.

Comment: Should this also work with raster data?

Comment: No.  Ogr is for vector data.  You need to call gdal functions, but see my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have ArcGIS. There is a very good worked example at http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Dataset_properties/000v0000002m000000/

Otherwise a common python library for geo-related tasks is [Shapely](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html#introduction). However, I think you might have more luck with [OGR/GDAL](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython). There is a tutorial [here](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/lectures/ospy_slides1.pdf), including how to get the extent (see page 18)

Comment: Hi Stev, i have QGis and want to develope python plugins to QGis..i referred the tutorial u suggested. But i dint get the statement "os.chdir('f:/data/classes/python/data')" please clarify..Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: If you just want to know the extent in QGIS go to the layer properties and look at the Metadata tab.

Comment: Hi..Sylvester Sneekly, thanks for your answer and i got the extent..but i want it by using the python script..

Answer (score 0):

You may have already discovered how trivial a task ArcPy makes this sort of question. Expanding further on MappaGnosis' answer, to get the full extents of the feature class using ArcPy, call the GetExtent() method of the Layer object:

```
fc = r"C:\some_folder\my_subfolder\myShapefile.shp"
ex = arcpy.mapping.Layer(fc).getExtent()
print "\t".join(map(str, [ex.XMin, ex.YMin, ex.XMax, ex.YMax]))
del fc, ex
```

The `arcpy.mapping.Layer()` method creates a reference to a feature class from a shapefile to an ArcSDE feature class. The `getExtent()` method returns an [`Extent`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000072000000) object with all kinds of properties including the coordinates we're after. Last, the `string.join(map(str, list))` is a shorthand way to print a tab-delimited list of the coordinates.

To list the extents for each feature, open a search cursor on the feature class and loop through it:

```
fc = r"C:\some_folder\my_subfolder\myShapefile.shp"
for ftr in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@", "RefName"]):
    ex = ftr[0].extent
    print "\t".join(map(str, [ftr[1], ex.XMin, ex.YMin, ex.XMax, ex.YMax]))
del fc, ftr, ex
```

The optional, second argument to the `SearchCursor()` method specifies what field values to return for each feature; if the argument is left out, then all field values will be returned.